# Show 1 of many selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little jquery show/hid script. The problem I have is it shows all of the slectors. I just want it to show the one that is inside the div that was clicked.

HTML

```
<!--row1 -->
    <div class="row resource-line-item">
     <div class="zone1">
       <h3 class="clickable">ANDALE.TTF - True Type Font</h3>
       <span class="edit-resource">Edit</span> 
     </div>
    <div class="zone2 printer-state">
       <p> Size: 4153344 <br>
           Date: Tuesday, March 26, 2013 2:14:14 PM</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="edit-Box"> </div>
    </div>

<!--row2 -->
    <div class="row resource-line-item">
     <div class="zone1">
       <h3 class="clickable">ANDALE.TTF - True Type Font</h3>
       <span class="edit-resource">Edit</span> 
     </div>
    <div class="zone2 printer-state">
       <p> Size: 4153344 <br>
           Date: Tuesday, March 26, 2013 2:14:14 PM</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="edit-Box"> </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#resource-list-area .edit-resource").on("click", function(event){
     $(this).next(".edit-box").toggle();
       //alert('hello')
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, guessing thats your markup

```
$("#resource-list-area").on("click", ".edit-resource", function(event) {
    $(this).closest(".row").find(".edit-Box").toggle();
});
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZBje/1

Comment: I had to change my markup, (next) no longer works because it's not in the parent. Thanks for the solution though. I voted up your answer, but am keeping my question open to find solution for updated markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```